# Issue with seaborn in sublime

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having an issue with `seaborn` in the sublime text editor.

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
sns.factorplot('Sex', data=data)
```

Here is the error:

```
Error 
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 73, in _mean    
ret = ret / rcount
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'long'
```

Comment: It says what's wrong right there: your did not convert the strings read from the CSV to numbers

Comment: sns.factorplot('Sex', data= data, kind="count")

Comment: i found the answere in seaborn 0.6  we need to add one more parameter sns.factorplot('Sex', data= data, kind="count") i got out of compilation error i am still unable to see factorplot please help after i run the code nothing is showing in sublime text editor

Answer (score 5):

As Arshad said in the comments, by just adding `kind="count"` to the command, it solves the issue. In this case, the code should look like the following.

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
sns.factorplot('Sex', data=data, kind="count")
```

Answer (score 0):

UserWarning: The `factorplot` function has been renamed to `catplot`. 
The original name will be removed in a future release. Please update your code. Note that the default `kind` in `factorplot` (`'point'`) has changed `'strip'` in `catplot`.
  warnings.warn(msg).
Hence I used:
sns.catplot('Sex',data=titanic_df,kind='count') and it works for me.