# Error make correlation and heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i want to see correlation for (survived, pclass, sex, age, and fare) on dataset titanic, having table :

Index([u'survived', u'pclass', u'sex', u'age', u'sibsp', u'parch', u'fare',
       u'embarked'],

> `correlation_matrix =np.zeros(shape=(5,5))` matrix 5x5

then i run  this to add thevalue from table to matrix :

```
for i, field1 in enumerate(df.columns):
for j, field2 in enumerate(df.columns):
        correlation_matrix[i,j] = pearsonr(df[field1], df[field2])[0]
```

got Error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQy1v.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that 'ret' is a string and you are trying to divide it by rcount which is presumably a float or int.

This looks like it may be a duplicate issue.

[Issue with seaborn in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012259/issue-with-seaborn-in-sublime)

Comment: i'am try use this : np.corrcoef(df['fare'], df['age']) but cant more than 2 table ? i mean, i make matrix 5,5 and then i want to add tothe matrix value from table